# Filling dataframe based on index and column from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering if it is possible to fill an empty dataframe with a predetermined index and columns with another dataframe?  Here I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2,  I want to fill df2 with values from df1, but keep the shape of the df2.  The columns will also not be the same order.

```
values1 = pd.Series(['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5'])
values2 = pd.Series([30,40,50,70,80])
values3 = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':values1,'C':values2,'B':values3})
df1 = df1.set_index(['A'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B','C','D'])
df2_a_val = pd.Series(['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8'])
df2['A'] = df2_a_val
df2 = df2.set_index(['A'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can do using `merge`:

```
df2 = (df2
      .merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
      .drop(['B','C'], 1)
      .rename(columns={'C_': 'C', 'B_': 'D'}))

      D     C     D
A                  
P1  NaN  30.0  10.0
P2  NaN  40.0  20.0
P3  NaN  50.0  30.0
P4  NaN  70.0  40.0
P5  NaN  80.0  50.0
P6  NaN   NaN   NaN
P7  NaN   NaN   NaN
P8  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hey, I actually made an edit, will this change if there is a change in the number of columns between the 2 dataframes?

Comment: Hey, just to clarify, when you add the suffix, you take notice of which column both tables have correct? And if it does have not a suffix that column is only existing in the primary table, which in this case is df2.  Since df2 has NaN values, we would take values from the df1 which would be indicated with the '_' suffix.

Comment: yes, that's correct, suffix is added to column which are common in both the tables. is that the expected output ?